# Im tryng to make a bot say a message when a user does a command

Tags: discord-jda

Ok so ive been trying for 4 hours to figure this out

My main.java is:

```
    import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
    
    import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args){
        JDABuilder jdaBuilder = JDABuilder.createDefault("token");
        JDA jda = null;
        PingPong pingPong = new PingPong();
        jdaBuilder.addEventListeners(pingPong);
        try {
            jda = jdaBuilder.build();
            }   catch (LoginException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my PingPong.java is:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class PingPong extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {
        if (e.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!ping")) {
           e.getChannel().sendMessage("pong").queue();
        }

    }

}
```

and i keep geting errors on like 9 (  e.getChannel().sendMessage("pong").queue();  )

Error:

```
java: cannot access java.util.function.Consumer
  class file for java.util.function.Consumer not found
```

How do i fix this? ive just been tying to make a test command to see if it eaven works plis help

idk if this has anything to do about it but im using
intellij
and im using jda version 4.2.0_168

Comment: You're using an outdated java version. You need at least jdk 8.

Comment: Minn im using jdk 8  i found the problem tho
i had to add some spaces infront of
e.getChannel().sendMessage("pong").queue();

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the main class by doing something like this.

```java
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("TOKEN")
                    .addEventListeners(new pingPong())
                    .build();
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also please look at [proper naming conventions in java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), and specifically how you properly name classes.